# Hide a field from a superclass in a subclass

Tags: java, field, mask, superclass

Let's say I have 3 classes:

```
class Foo
{    
    protected String var;
    public void doSomething()
    {
         // does something with var
    }
}

class A extends Foo
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
        // uses var slightly differently to Foo
    }
}

class B extends Foo
{
    protected int var; // hides Foo's var field
    public void doSomething()
    {
        // does something with B's var, but still in a similar fashion to Foo
    }
}
```

In this case, I know and want B's var field to hide Foo's and still be used in a similar way (printing its value or performing some calculation or whatever).
Intentionally hiding fields can make code hard to read, but is this an exception to that, or is it still just poor design?

**Edit:**
I do want A to inherit 'var' from Foo but I'd also like B to inherit everything except for var.

**Edit 2:**
Forgot to add the access modifiers to var.

Comment: If B IS-A Foo then why? Can you let us know what this variable is being used for and why does it need to change it's type?

Comment: In my case Foo's var is of type List<String>, and B's var is of type List<Item> where Item is a separate class all together. As you can tell, both use Lists but with different template types, and both still do the same thing (go through the list and do something to the elements).

Comment: access modifiers didn't matter unless they were not in the same package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't "override" fields in the same way that methods can be overridden. You'll need to use method overriding to implement this behavior. For example:

```
class Foo
{    
    private String var;

    Object getVar() {
        return var;
    }
}

class B extends Foo
{
    private int var;

    @Override
    Object getVar() {
        return var;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Based on your comment:

> `Foo`'s `var` is of type `List<String>`, and `B`'s `var` is of type `List<Item>` where `Item` is a separate class all together. As you can tell, both use Lists but with different template types, and both still do the same thing (go through the list and do something to the elements)

It really sounds like your classes should be generic, for example:

```
abstract class Foo<T> {

    List<T> list;

    // common logic
}

class A extends Foo<String> { }

class B extends Foo<Item> { }
```

Don't take this code too literally - it's just to suggest the possible design.

Comment: OP can't make *var* private because other sub classes need to inherit it. I think his question is more about if the way he is hiding the superclass variable in `B` correct or not (rather than on overriding).

Comment: @RaviThapliyal The subclasses inherit the getter instead.

Comment: Well actually, you can override the field, depending on how it is accessed.  `B myObj = new B(); assert myObj.var == "overridden value" // this works; Foo myObj2 = new B(); assert myObj2 == "overridden value" // this does not work`.  So field hiding can be done, and actually I have had to fix some production bugs unintentionally caused by it.

Comment: @SamGoldberg That's not overriding though, it's *hiding*, which isn't polymorphic.

Answer (score 0):

My *preference* is to avoid direct field access of fields in a super class in a subclass, because it reduces dependencies on the implementation of the super class. (There are definitely some time that I will make fields `protected` because I do expect to explicitly use them from a subclass, but that is not the norm).

What I prefer to do is to encapsulate field access inside getter/setter methods, and to intentionally make them protected or public so subclasses can override them explicitly. In general, I often find that direct field access inhibits refactoring or modifying the implementation later, by causing more classes to be updated than should be necessary.

In your case, if you are dealing with code someone else wrote, and don't have access to the source of the base class, then it makes sense.  But otherwise I wouldn't do it, because it may not be so obvious to other developers that you are intentionally hiding the field.  If this is only for your own use (and not other developers), then practically speaking, I don't think it matters much.